# Kotlin - Check if one map contains all entries from another

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm trying to create a function in kotlin that takes two maps and returns true if one is contained in another, that is, if all the entries in map A are in map B (but B can have other entries)

The code I have is

```
private fun matchesMap(map1: Map<String, Any>, reference: Map<String, Any>): Boolean {
    return reference.all { k, v ->  map1.get(k).equals(v) }
}
```

But this gives a `Type mismatch: inferred type is (Map.Entry<String, Any>, ???) -> Boolean but (Map.Entry<String, Any>) -> Boolean was expected` and I'm not sure what's wrong. I've tried to replace it with `map1[k] == v` but I still get the same error. How can I fix the compilation error?

Comment: There's already a function for this, but you need to use it on the entries rather than the maps themselves. `mapB.entries.containsAll(mapA.entries)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't compile is that you forgot a pair of parenthesis around `k, v`. This makes a big difference because with the parenthesis you're creating a lambda expecting 1 argument, which is [destructured](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) into 2 variables (`k` and `v`), while without parenthesis you're providing a lambda that expects 2 different arguments. The latter is incompatible with the signature of `all`, as correctly pointed out by @Gennady.

Also, another problem is caused by the `.equals` method, because `get` is returning a nullable value (what if there's no such key in the map?), so the equals method should be invoked as `?.equals`, which can be simplified to `==`. Also, `get` can be simplified too to `[]`.

Putting all together:

```
private fun matchesMap(map1: Map<String, Any>, reference: Map<String, Any>): Boolean {
    return reference.all { (k, v) ->  map1[k] == v }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to specification [all](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html) method - argument of lambda is Entry. You cannot get key and value directly, so change it to Entry.

Correct code:

```
reference.all { entry ->  map1.get(entry.key) == entry.value }
```

You should use Map method [equals](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-abstract-map/equals.html). It does the same.

Comment: `Map.equals` is not the same because it also checks for them being the same size. The OP wants to allow for the other map having additional entries that aren't in the first.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you're right. Method containsAll will be correct answer